# How to trust ssl certificate programatically while using Spring Rest Client

Tags: spring, ssl, spring-3, resttemplate, truststore

I am using resttemplate from spring for consuming the Rest Json Webservice

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
headers.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE); 
HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(glassRequest, headers);
postForObject = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, responseClass );
```

I am using above code for same. It works fine if there is no  ssl certification at provider end. However , I get 403 if he uses certificate.

I know this can be handled by below two approches :-
1. Add certificate in trust store of application server.[But i am not running this code from application server but my junit test class]
2. Two add the certificate in java trust store. [However , i want to schedule this junit from enviroment where I don't have access ]

Is this can be done programmatically ?? Like i will include the certificates in my source code itself and then refer them by reading from classpath while making call to service.